# How to add line numbers to large files fast?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm still working on an ETL program to load lots of data files into a Netezza database. One requirement of the import is that a leading line number is added in the datafile. Those datafiles may have all different sizes, starting from a few bytes up to > 4GB (approx. 13.000.000 lines and more).

The loader I wrote uses the Python threading module to spawn up to 10 threads at the same time. After lots of testing I figured out that whenever a thread is working on adding a line number to each line and write it to a new datafile, all other threads are blocked.

Skipping the counting part and adding it to each line cannot be skipped, so I have to think about an other solution. This could be either using multiprocessing instead of multithreading or changing the way a number is added to each line.

Here's the code I currently use for the counting part:

```py
from itertools import count

counter = count(0)
cnt = 0
file_in = open(orig_filename, 'rb')
with open(filename_tmp, 'wb') as file_out:
    skip = False
    for line in iter(file_in.readline, b''):
        if header_included is True:
            if skip is False:
                skip = True
                cnt = next(counter)
                continue
        else:
            if cnt == 0:
                cnt = next(counter)
        cnt = next(counter)
        new_line = f'{cnt}\t'.encode(encoding) + line
        file_out.write(new_line)
    if line:
        field_len = len(line.decode(encoding).split('\t'))
file_in.close()
```

Usually this piece of code it quite performant, but it seems that adding the line number is less I/O and more processor specific.

The whole script itself does a lot more, like moving files around, etc. but it seems that when a huge file is being counted, all other things are just waiting. Btw, don't know if this is relevant, but I have to use Python 3.6 due to system OS limitations. :(

Any hints or tipps for me? Many thanks in advance, kind regards, Thomas

Comment: "all other threads are blocked.": indeed, that is (standard) threading in Python for you. Under the hood, Python still uses a single process; it just switches back and forth between different threads where it can. It doesn't run them simultaneously.

Comment: Python 3.6; oof. What OS are you on?

Comment: Threads will not avail you. Just use `polars` to read the file in, add your new column and dump it back out

Comment: For parallel work, you could considering using multiprocessing instead.

Comment: Do you need Python? Can't you use `cat -n YOURFILE | databaseLoader`

Comment: @9769953 we're unfortunately still on RHEL7. If we would have RHEL8, then I could work on Python 3.8. But the machine is not under my maintenance, I have to work with the tools available ...

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, I could spawn a subprocess doing the job with `cat`, but Python is still the main language for the whole program.

Comment: Are you trying to parallelize the processing of each file? It's much easier to implement by processing multiple files simultaneously, each on its own process. For example, `find -name datafile | xargs -I {} -P 10 python3 script.py {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Threading will not avail you because of the Global Interpreter Lock and this is less about I/O. `multiprocessing` will probably cause you headaches with RAM use since the namespace is copied.

Just use an efficient dataframe library like `polars` in a single process. I don't know exactly how you want to handle the encoding since it's not clear in your question, but this should give you a scaffold. `polars` (unlike `pandas`) can use multiple threads for processing and can work on files larger than memory.

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import csv

# I need test data
with open('test.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows([['header_a', 'header_b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']])
    

df = pl.read_csv('test.csv')
df = df.with_columns(
    count = pl.lit(np.arange(len(df)))
)
df = df[['count', 'header_a', 'header_b']]
df.write_csv('test_out.csv')
```

Comment: Actually, I wonder whether 3.6 is supported. It would take me time to set up a test for that, but you might need to drop to `pandas`

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `polars`. Indeed an interesting library. Btw. the right code to add a column would be `df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(np.arange(len(df))).alias('count'))`.

Comment: @brillenheini the code does the same thing; I'm not sure there is a "right" way to do it when they're identical

Comment: I tried it with the line you answered me, which did not work, but this might have been a version problem due to I am using Python 3.6 and thus Polars is installed with 0.12.5

Comment: @brillenheini it will be a version issue. The library takes arbitrary expressions in the current version, but at least there is _a_ version that works with 3.6, so that answers my initial concern. However, I wonder how far behind the implementation is in terms of parallelism... hmm